# What can cause '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' to get deleted?

Tags: mysql, whm

All of a sudden I started to get this error message on my CentOS WHM Cpanel LAMP stack:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I restarted the MySQL server via WHM, MySQL started working again however, in just a few seconds/minutes it went down and the above error message returned. This happened several times.

I Googled around for a solution and confirmed that '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' was missing and simply created an empty file '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock', restarted the MySQL server via WHM and MySQL started working again and it did not go down this time.

My question is, what could have caused this in the first place?

And shouldn't the initial restart restore any missing /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock file? Also, why did the restart work and then the error returned?

If the /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock file was missing, the restart should not have worked until I recreated the /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock file?

Before the first failure, the server load did peak (but did not peak after).

Also, I got this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I changed the password via WHM which stopped that error, but then, the sock errors didn't go away.

Any ideas what happened?

Comment: is it a Windows or linux server?

Comment: @C0dekid the first sentence states **CentOS** and the path to the file in question is `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` - both indicating it's **not** Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It will require some more investigation but here are a few specific things to be aware of.

1.) When you are unable to connect to MySQL have you verified with "service mysql status" to check if it is running?  The chances are it probably is not and that also explains why mysql.sock would go away (when MySQL is shutdown you will see mysql.sock is deleted - you can test this with "service mysql shutdown")

2.) Note that recreating the mysql.sock as a plain file has no effect even if the server was running still (though I doubt it was running).  mysql.sock is a socket and not a normal file and can only be created through restarting MySQL.

3.) Most importantly you should browse your /var/lib/mysql/*.err log for errors which should give you a clue or hint of what the issue is.

4.) If #3 does not help clarify things you want to check your Apache logs for unusual activity.  A lot of database crashes or shutdowns are related to DOS attacks, hacking or even cPanel updates that fail (in the order of most likely from my experience).